# Append Line to All Files in a Directory Recursively in Python

Tags: python, os.walk

I am new to Python and looking for some syntax help.

I have a directory and sub-directories with *.properties files (over 100 files). I would like to append 2 lines of text to the end of every single file.

I am trying to use os.walk and f.write but unsure how to combine the two for my purposes. In the code below, I have also just tried to begin by appending 1 line of text but I would like the text to be 2 lines.

```
import os

dir_name = "C:\\Users\\<user>\\Desktop\\test\\" # Edit as needed


for parent, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir_name): 
    for fn in filenames:
        f = open(fn, 'a')  
        f.write("text\n")
        f.close()
```

When I run the script I provided, nothing happens to the files in "test"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filenames are not paths. You must concatenate the path to their directory and the filename:

```
f = open(os.path.join(parent, fn), 'a')
```

---

Also, that's unrelated to your issue, but instead of:

```
f = open(fn, 'a')  
f.write("text\n")
f.close()
```

a good ("pythonic") style is to do:

```
with open(fn, 'a') as f:
    f.write("text\n")
```

That takes care of properly closing the file, even if an error happens.

Answer (score 1):

this `f = open('fn', 'a')` should be         `f = open(fn, 'a')`

Comment: This answer correctly identifies the main issue, but often you'll need to use `os.path.join(parent, fn)` to get the full filename relative to the current working directory.